# (Legion-7-16IAX7) No Sound Dual boot Win 11 pro & Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (TAS2781 and Realtek ) Update (Cirrus)

Tags: dual-boot, sound, lenovo, realtek

### There is no output on the speakers even after upgrading to kernel 6.5.0 on ubuntu lts 22.04.

I searched the internet and found some links regarding the issue.
But I can't seem to figure out what  to do with the problemo.

posting the links :-

1. This is the exact model problem I have ... But the solution is given for Ubuntu 23.10 and a lower kernel version 6.4.0-rc5+

https://e2e.ti.com/support/audio-group/audio/f/audio-forum/1208376/tas2781-tas2781s-linux-drivers-for-lenovo-laptops

This solution seems to have been merge in the kernel(Main branch) but doesn't seem to work with my machine.

https://lore.kernel.org/all/20230818085836.1442-2-shenghao-ding@ti.com/

2. Other link with similar issues with lenovo legions but having trouble understanding the thread.

https://e2e.ti.com/support/audio-group/audio/f/audio-forum/1279290/tas2781-tas2781-lenovo-r9000p-laptop/4851710#4851710

How to solve the problem ?

Update !!!

Upgraded to 23.10...... Kernel version 6.6.21

Speakers on the external monitors started working ..... but the default speakers on laptop still don't.

Update !!!

Now a error has started popping up about cirrus i2c chip .
attaching the screenshot. Searched about the error. Has already been merged but seems to not work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOCTy.jpg)